# How to import csv file into mysql database with automatically increment in id into database table.id field is not in file,only on table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am importing a CSV file which contains 2 fields. But as it is imported, I want that there should be an increment in transactionid. But this id field is not in file.
Code for this is in PHP. Database used is MySql.
My Code:

```
do 
{
    if ($data[0])
     {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            )
        ");
     }
}
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok try this code

```
do 
{
   if ($data[0])
   {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(table name) VALUES
        ('".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."')
                 ");
   }
}
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your table on the `id` column, set the `auto_increment` parameter to true/active.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the name of that table where you really want to import in query.